# Angular event emitter: How to subscribe to 3rd party event?

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have a shared service to manage my openlayers map operations in angular 4 application.

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class MapService {

  public onMapLoadStart: EventEmitter<any>;

  constructor() {
    this.onMapLoadStart = new EventEmitter();
   }

  populateMapLoadStart = function(event){
    this.onMapLoadStart.emit(event);
  }
}
```

And I use service in my map component.

```
    import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
    import OlOsm from 'ol/source/osm';
    @Component({
      selector: 'my-map',
      templateUrl: './map.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
    })
    export class MapComponent implements OnInit {

      source: OlOsm;

      constructor(private mapService: MapService) { 
        mapService.onMapLoadStart.subscribe(item => this.source.on("tileloadstart", function(){}));??????
      }

      ....
      ...
```

the openlayers `source` object has an event named `tileloadstart`. I want to subscribe this event via my map service. Openlayers source event works like this:

```
this.source.on("tileloadstart", function(event){
    console.log(event);
}));
```

But this does not work.

Comment: Could you please provide a StackBlitz example to show what exactly goes wrong?